# My browser keeps sending me to the raw PHP file when I try to send form data to a raw text file?

Tags: php, html, http

sorry if the answer is really simple but I wanted to send data from a form on a modal to a raw text file using PHP but I can't seem to get it to work. It just redirects me to a PHP file and doesn't generate the text file.

HTML form:

```
                <!-- The Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                    <div class="modal-content">             
                    
                    <form action="action.php" method="POST">
                      <!-- Modal Header -->
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title"#>Input your details</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      </div>

                      <!-- Modal body -->
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="username">Username:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" required value="Enter Username" name="username" id="usr">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="psw">Password:</label>
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="psw" required value="Password" name="password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      
                      <!-- Password validation -->
                        <div id="message">
                          <h3>Password must contain the following:</h3>
                          <p id="letter" class="invalid">A <b>lowercase</b> letter</p>
                          <p id="capital" class="invalid">A <b>capital (uppercase)</b> letter</p>
                          <p id="number" class="invalid">A <b>number</b></p>
                          <p id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>8 characters</b></p>
                        </div>

                      <!-- Modal footer -->
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
 $path = 'data.txt';
 if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $fh = fopen($path,"a+");
    $string = $_POST['username'].' - '.$_POST['password'];
    fwrite($fh,$string); // Write information to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file
    exit;
 }
?>
```

I appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Are you seeing the raw PHP code on the screen, instead of the code actually being executed by the server? If so, you can find plenty of guidance on solving that in many places online already. Have you searched?

Comment: Yes that's what happened, would you mind guiding me on what i should be searching for online regarding that? I already tried to search on what to do when there is raw PHP code showing instead of the code executing.

Comment: Start here: there are literally dozens of answers - https://www.google.com/search?q=php+code+display+in+browser+instead+of+executing